# How to check if a list contains a list of lists inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to know how can I check in the shortest way possible if a list contains lists inside. I don't need to check a value, just the type of the list. I want to know if the objects inside a list are lists or not. Just that.

Thank you!

Comment: You can sue `isinstance` to check if a variable is an instance of a specific type. Then you can loop through the elements individually, somethink like `if isinstance(current_element, str)`

Comment: Not duplicated, I don't want to know if a list is inside other list, I just want to know if the objects inside a list are lists or not.

Comment: What about `list in map(type, your_list)`?

Comment: @Nkolot What about `['a', []]`, there's one list but not all elements are list. Improve your question, what is the expected output? Do you want to know if *all* elements are lists? Or do you want to know if *any* elements are lists?

Comment: I want to know if the objects inside a list are lists or not. Just that.

Comment: @Nkolot use all or any

Comment: @Nkolot Again, do *all* of them need to be lists, or is it enough if *some* of them are lists? My question should answer both of these cases (`all()` vs `any()`), but in the future you should provide information like this in your question. Ideally provide some example cases on how you wish to use the code too.

Comment: Okey, I come here from Java and I didn't know that possibility. All of them need to be lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `isinstance(x, list)` to see if `x` is an instance of `list`.

If you want to ensure that *all* elements in your list (let's call it `my_list`) are lists, use `all()`:

```
all(isinstance(x, list) for x in my_list)
```

If you just wanna know whether there are *any* lists inside of `my_list`, use `any()`:

```
any(isinstance(x, list) for x in my_list)
```

These both return a boolean value (`True`/`False`), so you can store it to a variable or use it in an `if` sentence or whatever:

```
if any(isinstance(x, list) for x in my_list):
    print('At least one list!')
else:
    print('No lists in my_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

A list can be mixed types, but you can find the type of any index in a list using the `type` method

```py
x = [1, 2, 'three', [4, 5, 6]] # This list contains int, int, str, list
for i in x:
    print(type(i))
```

Returns

```py
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check that with the isinstance method:

for example if you have a dictionary temp = {}

you can check that with

```
 print(isinstance(temp, dict)) # it ll return True if temp is a dictionary.
```

same for list and strings etc...

Answer (score 0):

To check if **any** of the items is a list you can do:

```
if list in map(type, my_list):
    # there is a list in `my_list`
```

To check if **all** items are lists you can do:

```
if {list} == set(map(type, my_list)):
    # all items are lists
```

---

You can be more explicit with:

```
def is_list(x):
    return type(x) == list
```

And then:

```
if any(map(is_list, my_list)):
    # some items are lists
```

Or:

```
if all(map(is_list, my_list)):
    # all items are lists
```

Make sure to add your handling for the empty list case.